# How to change showcase view circle size in android

Tags: android, showcaseview

I am using android showcase view in my application.

following library file used in my project

https://github.com/amlcurran/Showcaseview

I want to change showcase view circle size.

I was change radius size in radius file but can't effect.

Please help me.

Comment: use this library and create custom showCaseview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141856/android-showcase-view-how-to-use/52619873#52619873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change  theme of showcase view and change radius value from value folder.

String-> values->radious.xml

And change radios size.

Answer (score 7):

add your custom radii to you res/values/dimen.xml:

```
<dimen name="showcase_radius">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="showcase_radius_inner">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="showcase_radius_outer">60dp</dimen>
```

and use

new ShowcaseView.Builder(this, ***true***)
                .setTarget(viewTarget)
                .build();

Answer (score 0):

For material Showcase style you should use `showcase_radius_material` resource. `new ShowcaseView.Builder(this, true)` constructor is deprecated and there's no need to use it.

Currently supported resources:

```
<dimen name="showcase_radius">94dp</dimen>
<dimen name="showcase_radius_inner">96dp</dimen>
<dimen name="showcase_radius_outer">128dp</dimen>
<dimen name="showcase_radius_material">48dip</dimen>
```