# Not able to include the library to Android Studio Project

Tags: android, showcaseview

I am trying to include ShowcaseView library to my project using the dependency mentioned in readme file

```
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
```

But Android Studio gives error for this.
I am using Android Studio 1.0.2.
Can anybody tell me what am I missing here?

> Error:Could not download artifact 'library.aar
>   (com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0)': No cached version
>   available for offline mode

Comment: Check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildgradle0-9-1-available-for-offline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` include `http://jcenter.bintray.com` as a repository ***before*** `mavenCentral` like this:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Use in your project dependencies as usual:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
}
```

#### Why prior to mavenCentral?

Otherwise gradle will look first in `mavenCentral`, find `ShowCaseView` artifact with the same version, but won't find the package and will report an error, without looking for same artifact with another packaging in other repositories.

#### Additional Hint:

If you face this kind of error for any other libraries go to **[bintray.com](http://bintray.com)** ans search for the library that you want. If it is found there then click on the library and u can find the instructions on how to setup that library. Hope it helps many people who comes and searches for the same query.

Comment: Nice answer +1. Any reference supporting your ***"Why prior to mavenCentral?"*** part?

Comment: @SMR Here is a link to the gradle doc that answers ur query 

http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N10621

Comment: U can find even more info from this link too.... have a look into it ... http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories

Comment: try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141856/android-showcase-view-how-to-use/52619873#52619873

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that your are adding the `compile` line for the library correctly in the `Build.gradle (Module: app)` file in the dependency section.

Then make sure of two things:

1)Restart your IDE

2)You have an internet connection.

3)Adding the `MavenCentral()` to your repositories in the `build.gradle (Project: you_project_name)` in the `buildscript` section

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
```

4)Click on `Sync Now`

Have a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595686/1364896)