# ShowcaseView replacing or removing EndButton

Tags: android, showcaseview

So, I'm this library (https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView), it's working great but I need to hide the button it has because I really don't need it. I've tried using the method .replaceEndButton() by making it replace it with one invisible button I added to the XML file of the but it crashes

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by creating a button programmatically and making it with GONE visibility.

```
 Button button = new Button(getContext());
    button.setText("");
    button.setEnabled(false);
    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And then on the ShowcaseView builder method replaceEndButton(), I send this new button like this:

```
ShowcaseView sv = new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity())
            .withMaterialShowcase()
            .setTarget(new ViewTarget(fabIntercom))
            .hideOnTouchOutside()
            .replaceEndButton(button)
            .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme)
            .setContentTitle(R.string.showcase_main_title)
            .setContentText(R.string.showcase_main_message)
            .singleShot(42)
            //.setParent()
            .build();
```

Comment: Show this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141856/android-showcase-view-how-to-use/52619873#52619873

Comment: It has a bug! even with `singleShot` it overlays an invisible frame on screen lincluding my button! how can I fix this?