# ShowCaseView does not hide when touching outside

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2, showcaseview

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(mainTabActivity)
                            .withHoloShowcase()
                            .setTarget(new ViewTarget(recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView))
                            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.tutorial_welcome))
                            .setContentText(getString(R.string.tutorial_cardview_add))
                            .hideOnTouchOutside()
                            .build();
```

This is my code when attaching the showcaseview onto the recyclerview first item. It works although the animation seems to be laggy I don't know why, and also the problem is when I touch outside or press the "ok" button. The showcaseview does not hide instead I have to press the "ok" or touchoutside for a few times "four times" I think, to make it go away completely. Am I missing something?

I am using this https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView library.

I have tried giving it an onClickListener and calling removeAllViews() but it's crashing the app.

Comment: How should anyone here know what library you're even talking about? How about what you've tried so far? Did you try anything? Good resource:  [MCVE]

Comment: @NickCardoso Sorry, Thanks for the resource.

Comment: **Try This Library **
[ShowCaseView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141856/android-showcase-view-how-to-use/52619873#52619873)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, what I did was to directly initiate the whole thing in the adapter of the recyclerview and hold it in a condition that would prevent it from popping up more than once.